# Spring Boot Actuator: Exclude detail from component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-boot-actuator

Whenever I call `/actuator/health`, there's an instance in my IBM MQ COmponent that **shouldn't** be checked, in this case `mqQueueConnectionFactory` *(Because it's a method used to generate a `MQQueueConnectionFactory` and doesn't have the required authentication to connect to our queue)*. The names do match the configured beans, so e.g. `mqQueueConnectionFactory` matches the `mqQueueConnectionFactory` bean.

```json
{
    "status": "DOWN",
    "details": {
        "jms": {
            "status": "DOWN",
            "details": {
                "connectionFactory": {
                    "status": "UP",
                    "details": {
                        "provider": "IBM MQ JMS Provider"
                    }
                },
                "queueConnectionFactory": {
                    "status": "UP",
                    "details": {
                        "provider": "IBM MQ JMS Provider"
                    }
                },
                "mqQueueConnectionFactory": {
                    "status": "DOWN",
                    "details": {
                        "error": "com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'GIMLI_A1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'gimli-a1.it.company.net(1417)'."
                    }
                },
                "userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter": {
                    "status": "UP",
                    "details": {
                        "provider": "IBM MQ JMS Provider"
                    }
                },
                "cachingConnectionFactory": {
                    "status": "UP",
                    "details": {
                        "provider": "IBM MQ JMS Provider"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "db": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "tnvet": {
                    "status": "UP",
                    "details": {
                        "database": "DB2",
                        "hello": 1
                    }
                },
                "nk": {
                    "status": "UP",
                    "details": {
                        "database": "DB2",
                        "hello": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to define that certain details shouldn't be included in the health check? Unfortunately reworking of removing the bean is not a option.

---

Additional info:

**Java version**: 8
**Spring Boot version**: 2.1.9.RELEASE
**Spring Boot Actuator**: 2.1.9.RELEASE
**IBM MQ JMS Spring Boot Starter**: 0.0.3

Configuration file:

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {
    @Value("${ibm.mq.hostName}")
    private String mqHostName;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.port}")
    private int mqPort;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.queueManager}")
    private String mqQueueManager;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.channel}")
    private String mqChannel;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.user}")
    private String mqUser;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.password}")
    private String mqPassword;

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws JMSException {
        return userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter(mqQueueConnectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory() throws JMSException {
        return userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter(mqQueueConnectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory() throws JMSException {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();

        // Get these settings from the application properties
        cf.setHostName(mqHostName);
        cf.setPort(mqPort);
        cf.setQueueManager(mqQueueManager);
        cf.setChannel(mqChannel);
        cf.setTransportType(CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);

        return cf;
    }

    @Bean(name = "jmsPlatformTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager(CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory) {
        cachingConnectionFactory.setCacheConsumers(true);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(5);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setReconnectOnException(true);
        return new JmsTransactionManager(cachingConnectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory(//
            PlatformTransactionManager jmsPlatformTransactionManager, //
            CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory);
        defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setTransactionManager(jmsPlatformTransactionManager);
        defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setConcurrency("1-1");
        defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        return defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter(MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory) {
        UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter = new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter();
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setUsername(mqUser);
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setPassword(mqPassword);
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setTargetConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactory);
        return userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> myFactory(CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory,
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setSessionTransacted(false);
        factory.setConcurrency("1-1");
        configurer.configure(factory, cachingConnectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory(UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter) {
        CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        cachingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory(userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setCacheConsumers(true);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(5);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setCacheProducers(true);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setReconnectOnException(true);
        return cachingConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsOperations jmsOperations(CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory) {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory);
        jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(10);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove mqQueueConnectionFactory health check?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove that specific instance

Comment: check my answer. You can try that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove any custom health-check from your /actuator/health, you can use **@ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator** annotation.

```java
@Component
@ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator("mqFactory")
public class MqHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator { 
    @Autowired
    private MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory;
 
    @Override
    public Health health() {
        Health.Builder status;
        //your logic to check if mq is up
        if (mqQueueConnectionFactory is up) {
             status = Health.up();
        } else {
             status = Health.down();
        }
         return status.build();
    }
}
```

and in your properties.file

```
management.health.mqFactory.enabled=false
```